# query an indexed jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, json

I want to query a jsonb column with the `@>` operator.

This query gives results:

```
select * from json_table1
where p_attribute @> '{"age":"37"}'
```

This query doesn't fail but also doesn't give results:

```
select * from json_table1
where p_attribute -> 'age' @> '37'::jsonb
```

The table used in the example:

```
create table json_table1 (
    p_id int primary key,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    p_attribute jsonb,
    quote_content text
)
```

The index on `p_attribute`:

```
create index gin_idx on json_table1 using gin(p_attribute jsonb_path_ops)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `"37"` is a string, not a number, your second query would have to use a `jsonb` string:

```
... WHERE p_attribute -> 'age' @> '"37"'::jsonb
```

Note the double quotes around `37`.

Also note that this query wouldn't be able to use the index, while the first query can.

Comment: Why doesn't the second query use the index? Is there a way I can index keys and values seperately so I can text search like I would with to_tsquery?

Comment: Yes, then you have to add a regular B-tree index on `json_table1 ((p_attribute -> 'age'))`. Obviously such an index can only be used for `WHERE` conditions on that expression.